# How can I extract very large results from omnet++ in excel format without problems in loading the csv file?

Tags: export-to-csv, omnet++, veins, sumo, scalar

I am studying UVCAST protocol for Vehicular ad hoc networks using omnet, veins, sumo. When I execute export data of the results for a specific metric from the omnet to a csv file, and  I open the csv file in excel format in simulations folder ,then message appears that the entire file has not been loaded  because the number of rows exceeds 1,048576 rows "or 1,6384 columns". How can I solve the problem in coordination with Access. How can I extract very large results from omnet in excel format without problems in loading the whole file ? please help me for finding out the solution .thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. This is a limitation of a given spreadsheet program. They do not support arbitrarily large files because they were not meant to be a database. If you have to work with a large amount of data, you should use python with numpy and work with dataframes.

Comment: thanks , but how can I use Matlab with omnet for results ?

Comment: I have no experience with matlab, however you can export/convert simulation results to CSV which (I assume) could be used by matlab.